# ec2:RequesterVpc IAM condition does not work cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was in the middle of creating some peering connections (god rest my soul) IaC and locked down the IAM policy using the documented ec2:RequesterVpc to a map of known accounts.

My TF run assumes another role to operate on the accepter side.

The policy would look something like this.

```
  {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:xxx:vpc-peering-connection/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:*:xxx:vpc/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "ArnEquals": {
                "ec2:RequesterVpc": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:xxx-2:vpc/*"
            }
        }
    },
```

I continually received access denied when trying to accept the connection with the condition present.

After inspecting the context of a failed request in the encoded auth message, it is evident in fact `ec2:RequesterVpc` is not present in the context. Though I'm pretty sure we can't see the full context from that.

What I want to know is, am I right, or am I missing something? And to further that, is there any reliable documentation to read that gives info on when conditions will not be available?

Amazons own documentation says it should be, right here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/security-iam.html#vpc-peering-iam-accept

Going a little further, even this does not work, despite `ArnEquals` suggesting it does support wildcards.

```
"ArnEquals": {
    "ec2:RequesterVpc": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this you need to separate the Resource actions like

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:xxx:vpc-peering-connection/*",
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
            "ec2:RequesterVpc": "arn:aws:ec2:*:xxx-2:vpc/*"
        }
    }
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:xxx:vpc/*"
    ]
}
```

Here is a yaml cloudformation snippet of creating such role/policy

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: IAM peer-role
Outputs:
  PeerRequestRoleArn:
    Description: Arn of the peer request role
    Value: !GetAtt peerRole.Arn
Parameters:
  RequesterPeerAccountId:
    Type: String
Resources:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${RequesterPeerAccountId}-peerrequest-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Principal:
              AWS: !Ref RequesterPeerAccountId
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub ${RequesterPeerAccountId}-peerrequest-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection
                Resource: 
                  - !Sub arn:aws:ec2:*:${AWS::AccountId}:vpc-peering-connection/*
                Condition:
                  ArnEquals:
                    ec2:RequesterVpc: !Sub arn:aws:ec2:*:${RequesterPeerAccountId}:vpc/*
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection
                Resource: 
                  - !Sub arn:aws:ec2:*:${AWS::AccountId}:vpc/*
```